# Options for rendering svg using haxe/nme

Tags: svg, haxe, nme

There seems to be a couple of different projects with this goal, with different levels of completion. I have just done a quick search, but that was my first impression. So I thought I should ask, anyone who has tested some different options? What was your experience?

Comment: I haven't tested any of them, but I'd think the one that is on the HaxeNME Github account is the one I'd try first: https://github.com/haxenme/svg/tree/master/format/svg ... Maybe ask on the NME forums if anybody has experience with the various other libraries? http://www.nme.io/community/forums/

Comment: And if you find a good solution, make sure to leave an answer to your own question so the rest of us know in future :)

Answer (score 0):

I use SVG with Haxe and was a smoth experience, first I create all my svg's with inkscape and then manipulate it with jquery extern so you have something like this

`var width:Int = seatmap.innerWidth();
        var vsvg:SVGElement = cast(new JQuery("#seatmap").find("svg")[0],
            SVGElement);
        var height:String = vsvg.getAttribute("height");
        if (height > 1200) {
            vsvg.setAttribute('viewBox', "0 0 1200 "+ height);
        }else if (width <= 1200 && width > 1024) {
            vsvg.setAttribute('viewBox', "0 0 1500 "+ height);
        } else if (width <= 1024) { 
            vsvg.setAttribute('viewBox', "0 0 1900 "+ height);
        }`

also you can change attributes on the fly

```
new JQuery("#xxx-" + aaa.bb).attr("fill-opacity","1");
new JQuery("#aax-" + aaa.bb).attr("fill","#ff0");
```

You could use the Rafael.js and D3.js externs for haxe to render content on the fly, working with the javascript externs is the same as javascript but you have strong types and avoid the javascript weirdness.
Hope this helps.